# Hosting laravel project , doesn't read env file

Tags: laravel, hosting, web-hosting, environment

```
**I can't move files to '/' path and in htdocs this project don't read env file if i set key in app.php then can't load sql parameters from env , how to set?**
```

- Sorry for my eng

Answer (score 1):

You need to run the following command in order to create the correct encryption keys:

```
php artisan key:generate
```

This will fix your 'The only supported chiphers are AES-128-CBC ...' error.

You also need to edit your virtual host to make your the public directory the DocumentRoot cause now you are listing your application root and that is not good!